# Colocar permissão no login com restrição de acesso

Tags: java, swing

Estou usando um código que já era feito por alguém, fiz algumas modificações a respeito do que eu queria.

Esse código tem 2 tipos de acesso "Administrador e Funcionario" gostaria que quando a pessoa entrasse com o login do tipo Funcionário ela não conseguisse ver os seguintes itens (jMenu2,jMenuItem12,jMenuItem13) que se encontra na jframe "Menu" que abre logo após efetuar o login. Alguém poderia me dar um força?

Classe Main

```
package Classes;

import Telas.Menu;
import Telas.Login;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Login().setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Classe SQLConnection

```
package Classes;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author rafael
 */
public class SQLConnection {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection java_db() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-33483CU:1433;databaseName=DADOSPROD;user=PROD");
            return conn;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Tela Login

```
package Telas;

import Classes.SQLConnection;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author rafael
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LoginUsuario.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        conn = SQLConnection.java_db();
        Toolkit toolkit = getToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        setLocation(size.width / 2 - getWidth() / 2,
                size.height / 2 - getHeight() / 2);

    }


private void EntrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

            if (LoginUsuario.getText().equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Campo Usuário está vazio");
            } else if (LoginSenha.getText().equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Campo Senha está vazio");
            } else {

                String sql = "select id,username,password,division from Users Where (username =? and password =? and division =?)";

                try {
                    int count = 0;

                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    pst.setString(1, LoginUsuario.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, LoginSenha.getText());
                    pst.setString(3, txt_divisao.getSelectedItem().toString());

                    rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    {
                    }
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        int id = rs.getInt(1);
                        Emp.empId = id;
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                    String access = (txt_divisao.getSelectedItem().toString());

                    if (access.equals("Administrador")) {

                        if (count == 1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem Vindo!");
                            Menu j = new Menu();
                            j.setVisible(true);
                            this.dispose();

                        } else if (count > 1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicado, nome de usuário ou acesso à senha negado");
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O nome de usuário e a senha não estão corretos");
                        }
                    } else if (access.equals("Funcionario")) {

                        if (count == 1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem Vindo!");
                            Menu j = new Menu();
                            j.setVisible(true);

                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O nome de usuário e a senha não estão corretos");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

                } finally {

                    try {
                        rs.close();
                        pst.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }

            }
```

Tela Menu

```
package Telas;

/**
 *
 * @author rafae
 */
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Menu
     */
    public Menu() {
        initComponents();
    }

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
      teste1 tela = new teste1();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}                                          

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    teste2 tela = new teste2();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}                                          

private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    teste3 tela = new teste3();
    tela.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}
```

Classe Emp dentro das telas

```
package Telas;

/**
 *
 * @author rafae
 */
class Emp {

    static int empId;

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Botão voltar

```
Menu tela = new Menu(false); // setei false igual no usuário que você fez.
tela.setVisible(true);
dispose();
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione um [mcve] para que seja possivel testar o código.

Comment: Falta os itens de menu que são composto por uma barra de menu e alguns itens de menu. vou postar um exemplo

Comment: Bom, como você não está conseguindo criar uma versão simples e sem dependencias do seu código, posso postar um exemplo totalmente diferente com uma solução e você adaptar pro seu código ai, pode ser?

Comment: poste que farei o teste

Comment: Olá
Você está usando um banco de dados? se sim crie uma tabela para o login, assim todo login feito sera armazenado nessa tabela com isso você pode fazer o busca do ultimo login feito e comparar se o tipo de usuário é adm ou comum, fazendo está comparação você consegue desabilitar os botões que quiser.

Comment: @WagnereliasdeAndrade, sim, eu já tenho essa tabela para login e agora está funcionando meu código. só estou com um problema que expliquei na ultima resposta

Answer (score 2):

Analisando o código, o jeito mais simples possível de se fazer isso é criar um parâmetro booleano no construtor da sua tela `Menu` que informe se o usuário tem acesso a todas as opções dos menus ou não.

Quando o usuário for Gerente, passe `true` e quando for funcionário, passe `false`. E na classe da tela `Menu`, use este parâmetro passado para definir a visibilidade dos menus que você deseja que sejam baseados em nível de acesso.

Como você não forneceu um [**exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](/help/mcve), fiz o exemplo abaixo para ilustrar minha sugestão. Fique atento a classe `MenuIFrame`, nela é que eu fiz a verificação que você precisa aplicar na sua tela `Menu`, e na classe `LoginIFrame` eu passo o valor booleano conforme a opção selecionada num combobox(obviamente no seu código você vai separar de acordo como você valida quando o login é de funcionario ou gerente):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoginWithRestrictionsTest extends JFrame {

    private JDesktopPane desktopPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            LoginWithRestrictionsTest frame = new LoginWithRestrictionsTest();
            frame.createAndShowGUI();
        });
    }

    public LoginWithRestrictionsTest() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        this.desktopPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        LoginIFrame internalframe = new LoginIFrame();
        internalframe.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        desktopPane.add(internalframe);
        internalframe.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        internalframe.setVisible(true);

        setContentPane(desktopPane);
        setTitle("Login Demo");

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * CLASSE LoginIFrame
 *
 */

class LoginIFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private JTextField userField;
    private JTextField passField;
    private JButton btnLogin;
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
    MenuIFrame pFrame;

    public LoginIFrame() {
        super("LoginIFrame", false, true, true, true);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setSize(250, 200);

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        this.lblNewLabel = new JLabel("User:");
        this.lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        this.lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 32, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(this.lblNewLabel);

        this.lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Pass:");
        this.lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        this.lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 57, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(this.lblNewLabel_1);

        this.userField = new JTextField();
        this.userField.setBounds(66, 29, 121, 20);
        getContentPane().add(this.userField);

        this.passField = new JTextField();
        this.passField.setBounds(66, 54, 121, 20);
        getContentPane().add(this.passField);

        this.btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        this.btnLogin.setBounds(98, 119, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(this.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (pFrame != null) {
                pFrame.dispose();
            }
            pFrame = new MenuIFrame(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Gerente"));
            getParent().add(pFrame);
            pFrame.setVisible(true);
        });

        setLocation(xOffset, yOffset);

        this.comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        this.comboBox.addItem("Funcionario");
        this.comboBox.addItem("Gerente");
        this.comboBox.setBounds(66, 85, 121, 20);

        getContentPane().add(this.comboBox);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * CLASSE MenuIFrame
 *
 */
class MenuIFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xOffset = 350, yOffset = 30;

    public MenuIFrame(boolean isFullLevelAccess) {
        super("MenuIFrame", false, true, true, true);

        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocation(xOffset, yOffset);

        JMenu menu1, menu2;
        JMenuItem menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3, menuItem4, menuItem5;
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menu1 = new JMenu("Menu 1");
        menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
        menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Item 3");
        // Esse sub-item só estará acessivel
        // se o usuario tiver acesso completo
        menuItem3.setEnabled(isFullLevelAccess);

        menu1.add(menuItem1);
        menu1.add(menuItem2);
        menu1.add(menuItem3);

        menu2 = new JMenu("Menu 2");
        // Esse menu e todos os seus sub-itens só estarão acessíveis
        // se o usuario tiver acesso completo
        menu2.setEnabled(isFullLevelAccess);
        menuItem4 = new JMenuItem("Item 4");
        menuItem5 = new JMenuItem("Item 5");

        menu2.add(menuItem4);
        menu2.add(menuItem5);

        menuBar.add(menu1);
        menuBar.add(menu2);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    }
}
```

Executando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> No código, utilizei o `setEnable` que desativa o componente para alteração ou acesso, mas ainda o mantém visível na tela. Se quiser ocultar completamente, troque por `setvisible`.

Saliento que o código acima foi somente para ilustrar o conceito explicado no inicio(do uso de booleano), não é necessariamente para que se adote como solução substituta ao que já fez.

---

Adaptando no seu código, seria algo como abaixo na classe `Login`(precisa ser testado):

```
 if (access.equals("Administrador")) {

        if (count == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem Vindo!");
            Menu j = new Menu(true);
            j.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();

        } else if (count > 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicado, nome de usuário ou acesso à senha negado");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O nome de usuário e a senha não estão corretos");
        }
    } else if (access.equals("Funcionario")) {

        if (count == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bem Vindo!");
            Menu j = new Menu(false);
            j.setVisible(true);

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O nome de usuário e a senha não estão corretos");
        }
```

E na classe `Menu`, algo parecido com o abaixo dentro do construtor:

```
public Menu(boolean isFullLevelAccess) {
    initComponents();
    jMenu2.setEnable(isFullLevelAccess);
    jMenuItem12.setEnable(isFullLevelAccess);
    jMenuItem13.setEnable(isFullLevelAccess);
}
```

**Obs.:** Se `jMenuItem12` e `jMenuItem13` forem opções do `jMenu2`, você não precisa aplicar a restrição a eles, apenas ao menu.

---

### Restrições

Apesar de funcional, essa forma é bastante simplista e não vai adequar se você tiver mais de 2 perfis de nível de acesso(ex.: alem de funcionario(limitado) e gerente, você resolva criar um perfil diretor com opções que só ele veja). Mas ao menos ela já serve de inspiração, caso necessite de outros níveis de acesso, como o uso de `ENUM` ao invés de booleano, ou criar objetos de funcionários com um campo onde fala qual a função dele a nível hierárquico, mas explicar isso fugiria bastante do objetivo da pergunta.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61720/discussion-on-answer-by-diegofm-colocar-permissao-no-login-com-restricao-de-aces)